# embed google maps in IE

Tags: google-maps, browser, compatibility, google-maps-embed

I am trying to do a simple google map embed but it does not work in internet explorer. I went to google maps clicked the link button and then copy and pasted the embed code. It is working in all the other browsers. Does anyone know how to make it work in IE? I find it hard to believe that google would just make the embed code incompatible.

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=2220+Haine+Drive,+Suite+45+78550&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=44.744674,107.138672&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=2220+Haine+Dr,+Harlingen,+Cameron,+Texas+78550&amp;view=map&amp;z=14&amp;ll=26.176442,-97.667951&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=2220+Haine+Drive,+Suite+45+78550&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=44.744674,107.138672&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=2220+Haine+Dr,+Harlingen,+Cameron,+Texas+78550&amp;view=map&amp;z=14&amp;ll=26.176442,-97.667951" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

this is in IE8. the map works when I switch to compatibility mode. I don't think the users of the site would even know what compatibility mode is, so I want to figure out how this can work.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a hack, but I think you can use

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

in order to tell IE8 to emulate IE7.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It didn't really work. It turns out that the map was not loading correctly because the div that it was in was display:none; . The div was meant to appear when you clicked on something. Apparently google maps don't render when the div is hidden at first. I figured out how to work around it though.

Comment: It's enough to replace `display: none` with `visibility: hidden`. If you also want to make content stop taking up place in this case, while hiding it also change it's `position` to `absolute` or `fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

solution is simple: just find the ll parameter in iframe's src... ll is the center position of the map. So find another coordinate on google map which is a little bit over or below your main marker. copy the new coordinates and change ll on src ... So when you show/hide map, you see your marker is centered, or at least somewhere on the map